# How to predict blob image in keras model?

Tags: python, api, tensorflow, keras

i want to load an image in keras model from blob. I have two api, one for the backend and business logic and another one for predict the image from keras model, then i want to upload the image to gcp bucket and from api model get the blob data from image and predict the image without download the image in the server. How can i do it?

I want to make this with the h5 file. If you can say me, i would appreciate.

thanks.